# R Formula to calculate rate of interest

Tags: r, rate

Is there a R function to calculate "Rate" similar to the one available in python?

In Python: `numpy.rate(nper,pmt,pv,fv)`

Thank you
S

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the package [financial](http://cran.r-project.org/package=financial) may have what you are looking for, but as you supplied no example it is a little difficult to asses for sure.

Comment: More specifically, when you load the package try ?tvm